# Sum of group but keep the same value for each row in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame, I want to create a new variable by sum of each ID and group, if I sum normal,dimension of data reduce, my case I need to keep and repeat each row.

```
ID <- c(rep(1,3), rep(3, 5), rep(4,4))
Group <-c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2)
x <- c(1:12)
y<- c(12:23)
df <- data.frame(ID,Group,x,y)
   ID Group  x  y
1   1     1  1 12
2   1     1  2 13
3   1     2  3 14
4   3     1  4 15
5   3     1  5 16
6   3     1  6 17
7   3     2  7 18
8   3     2  8 19
9   4     1  9 20
10  4     1 10 21
11  4     1 11 22
12  4     2 12 23
```

The output with 2 more variables "sumx" and "sumy". Group by (ID, Group)

```
   ID Group  x  y sumx sumy
1   1     1  1 12    3   25
2   1     1  2 13    3   25
3   1     2  3 14    3   14
4   3     1  4 15   15   48
5   3     1  5 16   15   48
6   3     1  6 17   15   48
7   3     2  7 18   15   37
8   3     2  8 19   15   37
9   4     1  9 20   30   63
10  4     1 10 21   30   63
11  4     1 11 22   30   63
12  4     2 12 23   12   23
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As short as:

```
df$sumx <- with(df,ave(x,ID,Group,FUN = sum))
df$sumy <- with(df,ave(y,ID,Group,FUN = sum))
```

Comment: how we use data.table

Comment: I got it setDT(df)[,':='(sumx =sum(y), sumy=sum(x)), by=.(ID, Group)][]

Comment: @Stat - it might be a bit more extensible to `cols <- c("x","y"); df[, paste0("sum",cols) := lapply(.SD, sum), by=.(ID,Group), .SDcols=cols]` - works the same for 30 columns or 3.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID, Group) %>%
   mutate_each(funs(sum)) %>%
   rename(sumx=x, sumy=y) %>%
   bind_cols(., df[c("x", "y")])
```

If there are only two columns to `sum`, then

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID, Group) %>%
    mutate(sumx = sum(x), sumy = sum(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get what you want if it is a single column and in case you have more than 1 column then add accordingly:

```
library(dplyr)

data13 <- data12 %>%

  group_by(Category) %>%

  mutate(cum_Cat_GMR = cumsum(GrossMarginRs))
```