# Sum of group but keep the same value for each row in pandas

Tags: pandas

How to solve same problem in this link [Sum of group but keep the same value for each row in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690042/sum-of-group-but-keep-the-same-value-for-each-row-in-r) using pandas?

I can generate separate `df` have the sum for each group and then merge the generated `df` with the original.

Comment: post the example as a dataframe and highlight what you did and where u got stomped. someone will help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` & `transform` as below to get your output.

```
df['sumx']=df.groupby(['ID', 'Group'],sort=False)['x'].transform(sum)
df['sumy']=df.groupby(['ID', 'Group'],sort=False)['y'].transform(sum)
df
```

**output**

```
ID  Group   x   y   sumx    sumy
1   1   1   1   12  3   25
2   1   1   2   13  3   25
3   1   2   3   14  3   14
4   3   1   4   15  15  48
5   3   1   5   16  15  48
6   3   1   6   17  15  48
7   3   2   7   18  15  37
8   3   2   8   19  15  37
9   4   1   9   20  30  63
10  4   1   10  21  30  63
11  4   1   11  22  30  63
12  4   2   12  23  12  23
```